# How is the reduced matrix of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to generate the characteristic polynomial of the matrix below, from the reduced matrix. But the calculations are not correct, because, probably, my reduced matrix is wrong. I hope this community helps.

[image]

Reduced matrix:

(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 &  \, \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} &  \, \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} &  \, \sqrt{n - \frac{2}{n - 1}} \\
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} & 0 & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} & 0 \\
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} & 0 & 0 \\
 \, \sqrt{n - \frac{2}{n - 1}} & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got $$ \left( \; \; x^4 -\left( \frac{3}{2} + \frac{n^2-5n+6}{n-1}\right) \,x^2  - \,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \, x + \left(  \frac{n^2-5n+6}{n-1}  \right) \;  \right) \; x^{n-4}  $$

This assumes that the matrix is $n$ by $n$  which is my best guess. Note that most of the eigenvalues are zero; it is symmetric so all are real.